# How to build a docker image with Stack Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am using [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) to build my Haskell project and would like to build a docker image from it.

I've found that Stack supports [Docker integration](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/), but as I tried it does not build for me ready to use docker image from my project.

The statement `stack docker pull`, that describes in the section https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/#use-stack-as-normal, it downloads the Haskell compiler

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
golang                         1.12.9              669220934599        3 months ago        814MB
kindest/node                   v1.15.3             8ca0c8463ebe        4 months ago        1.45GB
fpco/stack-build               lts-14.17           9adc774bb5e5        4 months ago        8.52GB
gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64   blue    

1db936caa6ac        8 months ago        23MB
```

but it does not build an image.

The question is, how to build a docker image from my haskell project with Stack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the purpose of the Stack Docker integration is simply to perform builds within the container, not necessarily to *produce* a container. I would recommend using the [official Haskell Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haskell/) and a Dockerfile to build the image instead.